# Execute condition over a list\set of elements

Tags: c#, dynamic, expression, ienumerable

Let's say I have a list of elements:  `["A", "B", "C", "X"]`
and a dynamic condition that to check against that list, for example:  `"A" && "D"`, so "A" and "D" must be part of the list to satisfy condition.

Most of the `IEnumerable` commands do apply a `Func` or `Predicate` over the individual elements, while in my case I want the condition to be applied over the whole list.

How could I verify that the given list meets the dynamic condition,  `list.Meets(condition)`?

I have tried converting the string condition to `Expression` but the solution gets too complex.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. So you got an array of 4 characters. Now you want to check if that array contains all elements of conditionArray A & D

Comment: Yes I want to check the **dynamic** condition e.g. A & D against the list of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up building a little condition parser.
The parser is able to process string conditions containing And or Or logic expressions and it's also able to process parentheses.

here is the link to the solution:
https://github.com/aberbegall/ConditionParser

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using Linq

```
public bool IsMatch(char[] arrToCheck, char[] condition)
{
    return condition.All(ch => arrToCheck.IndexOf(ch) > -1);
}
```

You can also use extension method

```
public static bool IsMatch(this char[] arrToCheck, char[] condition)
{
    return condition.All(ch => arrToCheck.IndexOf(ch) > -1);
}
```

so you can consume it like this

```
myArray.IsMatch(['A', 'D']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the point is that the condition is dynamic... The IsMatch() method won't work with condition like this "A" And "D" Or "X". I cannot restrict it to just All() or Any() Linq conditions